# Как сделать, чтобы имя пользователя Telegram отображалось ссылкой?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Есть бот, который встречает нового участника группы его именем и текстом

[image: Пример текста]

Как сделать, чтобы имя отображалось ссылкой? пример -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***Пример кода***

```py
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["new_chat_members"])
def handler_new_member(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "{} {},  Добро пожаловать в чат" 
                     .format(message.from_user.first_name,
                             message.from_user.last_name), disable_web_page_preview=True, )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["new_chat_members"])
def handler_new_member(message):
   bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "[{} {}](tg://user?id={}),  Добро пожаловать в чат "
                     .format(message.from_user.first_name,
                             message.from_user.last_name, message.from_user.id), disable_web_page_preview=True, parse_mode="Markdown")
```